# Cannot creat a react native tabs project with expo

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

I'm new on react native but when i try to create a new project with tabs using expo i recive this error and i cant find a solution any help please ?
[the error sreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4p7A.png)

Comment: It would be more useful for all in the SO community if you can paste the error message in your question, so other people can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have Git installed, as described in the installation guide: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/get-started/installation/

Comment: Thank you It works :)